# UITableViewCell Drawing Performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, performance, uitableview

I've been looking around to boost my UITableView performances and in doing so I was looking for a "sweet spot" of time it takes my cellForRowAtIndexPath method to perform.

I'm trying to do as liitle work as possible in there and caching lots of stuff.

Currently it goes between 0.002sec and 0.015sec (NSLogged)

Any idea what is fast/too slow ?

I'm getting a personnal sense of it by just scrolling and "feeling it" but was wondering about that "sweet spot number".

Best,
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Delete `NSLog()` 
In iPhone simulator and iPhone device both having console. So When you NSLogged values will  delay your program.
 So delete the `NSLog()` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: and try to profile yours project via instruments tool